# Show users submited address in google map infowindow when clicked (Wordpress and ACF plugin)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

guys I hope you can help me out with this issue. Bassically I'm trying to achive next goal:
Users fills out form (Buddyform + ACF plugin)-> Automatically post are being created from users submited form information

But there is a problem with that since one if the forms fields is Google Map field (created in ACF). 
Transaction from form to post is very nice. But for some reason information about selected address is missing. Meaning that you can see marker on map and you can move map, but you can't see what is exact address.

The idea was to include address in infowindow which would open onclick. But so far I understood just how to include manually written text (content : "text here"). But I want that in infowindow would appear address from Buddyform that user submited.

Is there a way to do so? 
You can see my testing [here](http://budget-smile.com/2018/02/08/fer/)
Since am not really good with coding I use plugins for custom fields creation (ACF plugin) and in order to show custom fields in post (wpView plugin)

Comment: Are you using the custom field [input_admin_enqueue_scripts](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/) to put in the maps api javascript code?

Comment: you can create dynamically the content of the info windows and use html elements to fill them (combined with data stored in variables), look this example for some idea of what you can actually do. http://jsbin.com/yudifahehi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what it exactly means. I think I added something simillar  like that in function.php when I needed to make sure that Google map appears in form in first place (otherwise there was errors). "wp_enqueue_script"

Comment: my mistake, I thought you were using the Google Maps javascript API are you not?

Comment: I'm using ACF plugin which provides possibilty to add custom field "Google maps", that probably uses Google maps js api. I guess so  [link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/) Thank you for example, I just not sure how it can be modified in order to show address in infowindow

Answer (score 0):

OK from what I can see from the [documentation link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/) in your comments. You have to add the code from the **Helpers** section into your page template.

In the `add_marker($marker, map)` method you can make another api call to get a human readable address of the marker location.

```
function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

  // var
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), 
      $marker.attr('data-lng') ),
      formatAddress = "";

  // create marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position  : latlng,
      map       : map
  });
```

Using the `latLng` variable to make request to the [Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) in order to get a formatted address from the variable's lat/lang coordinates.

```
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'location': latLng}, function(results, status) 
    {  
      if (status == 'OK') {
      formatAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });

// add to array
map.markers.push( marker );
```

Then you when add the infowindow you can put the formatted address as it's body content.

```
  // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
  if( $marker.html() )
  {
      // create info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content     : formatAddress
    });

    // show info window when marker is clicked
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        infowindow.open( map, marker );

    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Franco! Thank you for feedback I will try this out and get you know how it went :)

Comment: In the [link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/) you provided under the **Helpers** section it says that _"Both examples below require the following CSS and JS to be available to the page template. Please note that both the CSS and JS can be modified to your liking"._ This means that you can find and modify the .js file ACF generates in your project and realize the modifications in my answer.